# How are generic return values inferred in typescript methods?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to understand better how typescript infers return types with generics. If a method using a generic type as return value is called without a generic type parameter, how is the return type inferred by typescript? I understand that a generic in-parameter can easily be inferred by the type sent in but not how a return parameter gets inferred if no generic type parameter is supplied.

```js
// Call: 
this.getSomething(value);

// Method signature:
getSomething<T>(inParameter: string): T { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the `getSomething()` method:

```
getSomething<T>(inParameter: string): T {
  return null!; // <-- this isn't safe, whatever you put here
}
```

You didn't show the implementation in there, so I'm not sure what it thinks it's doing.  But the signature itself is suspect... `getSomething()` claims it can return a value of type `T` *for any type that the caller chooses* (or that the compiler infers for the caller), with only a `string` input.  This is unlikely to be true, or at the very least cannot be easily verified to be type safe.

I mean, nothing stops me from writing `this.getSomething<string>("abc")` and then `this.getSomething<number>("abc")`. But since the type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) upon compiling TypeScript to JavaScript, both of those calls will be emitted as just `this.getSomething("abc")`.  Probably that would be the same result for both calls, and since it's impossible for that result to be *both* a `string` *and* a `number`, at least one of those TypeScript calls is wrong.

---

But let's move on to your question as stated:

If you just call `this.getSomething(value)`, the inference will likely fail and `T` will become `{}` or [`unknown` depending on the version of TypeScript you're using](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown).

```
const hmm = this.getSomething("value"); // const hmm: unknown
// inference fails, T inferred as unknown
```

If you call `const t: string = this.getSomething(value)` it will use [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing)
 of `t` to decide that `T` must be `string`:

```
const t: string = this.getSomething("value");
// contextual typing, T is inferred as string
```

---

But it's better for both safety and inference for if caller supplies a parameter of type `T` or something which could possibly itself produce a value of type `T`.  For example:

```
getSomethingReasonable<T>(inParameter: string, tArray: T[]): T {
  return tArray[inParameter.length];
}

const okay = this.getSomethingReasonable("value", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);   
// inference on tArray, T is number
```

It's safer because the input `tArray` provides a runtime mechanism to produce a value of type `T` even with type erasure.  And, as you noted, it's a good way to infer `T`.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)